# How to tell Maven to execute testng tests one by one each in new JVM instance?

Tags: maven, jvm, testng

Is it possible to tell Maven to execute every testng test in new JVM instance (fork) in serial mode, i.e. one by one.

The configuration below works for junit, but not works for testng

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
         <forkMode>always</forkMode>
   </configuration>
```

Does anybody know how to set for testng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ben75, Thanks for your answer, But it doesn't work for me.

The key point is we use suiteXmlFiles to specify which case to run, and if we use suiteXmlFiles, the forkMode or (forkCount resuseForks) don't work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        ...
```

It's a very expensive configuration (i.e. it will take a long time to run your tests... so it's better to not use it, but you probably have some (good ?) reasons to use it).

This solution is the way to go since version 2.14, so I suggest you to upgrade your surefire-plugin version.

the reference is [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)